# How to Call a function of Controller From Twig

Tags: php, twig, slim

This is my view:

```
<div class="CSlider">
<div class="CProducts" >
<table>
<tr>
{% for count in 1..result|length %}
<td>
{% block tile %}
{% include 'tile.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
<h1>
{{ result[ count - 1 ].id }}
</h1>
</td>
{% if count is divisible by (6) %}
</tr>
<tr>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is my controller:

```
class COlxMyAdsController extends COlxDatabaseHandler {
protected $view;
public function __construct($container){
parent::__construct($container);
$this->view=$container->view;
}
public function fetchMyLiveAdIdsByUserId( Request $request, Response $response ) {
$args=$request->getParams();
$args=$args['id'];
$results = $this->m_objOlxUserDetails->fetchMyLiveAdIdsByUserId($args);
return $this->view->render($response,'profile.twig',['result' => $results]);
}
}
```

I want to call a function of the controller from the view. How can I do this using Twig?

Comment: What is the purpose of calling a controller method from a view? This looks so wrong.

Comment: as Nima said, calling the controller from the view is bad practice. you should prepare the data for the view before calling render or use ajax or something that uses the proper flow of calls. but if you really-really need to do somethink like that, you can register global functions to the twig engine - so that these can be called anywhere in any view: [see the details here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html)

Comment: so you mean to say i can call controller function from javascript right so can you suggest me how can i do this

Comment: Yes it is working and got the experience now to how make such Tiny things working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we can Use Exit_Tags

Through which we can assign a URL to that exit_tag to call this function